# What are interesting corollaries of a manifold being parallellizable?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

This is a heavily edited (in fact, a complete rewrite) of a question I asked badly a few days ago. I am editing as opposed to asking a new question as there are already several relevant answers.

I thought that perhaps a parallelizable manifold could be said to be "simpler" in some way.

Initially I thought things like "maybe it is possible to equip them with a flat metric" however, this is obviously false as $S^3$ is parallelizable. Or "maybe it is always possible to embed them in $\mathbb{R}^n$" for some small where $n$ smaller than twice the dimension of the manifold. Or perhaps "there is a structure on these manifolds that is not present on normal ones, like a Lie group structure but obviously not that". Or perhaps "we can say something about the topological invariants of such a manifolds"?

In particular, I was wondering if there is any intuitive or deep reason behind the statement "all orientable 3-manifolds are parallellizable". Does it have anything to do with the 3-sphere being parallellizable? Is that a stupid thing to say?

Being parallellizable seems like such a special property, I was wondering what the connections between different parallellizable manifolds are (other than, of course "there are not obstructions to this manifold being parallellizable")

Comment: $S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is not parallelizable

Comment: Yes John, that is my point. I guess it cannot tell us very much about the geometry of the manifold as I would expect the geometry of spheres to be similar and yet $S^3$ is parallelizable while $S^2$ is not

Comment: *Does a group being abelian tell us anything about the group, or is it just a "neat fact"?* Do you see how unanswerable your question is?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi if you told me that all groups fulfilling certain condition like "is of prime order", were abelian and I asked "why" I believe that would certainly be an answerable question!!

Comment: As phrased ("Does ... being “parallelizable” tell us anything...?", you don't exactly have a question, and I've voted to close. Of course parallelizability tells you something: In fact, it's a "rare" property among manifolds. But presumably you've encountered the property for the first time, and want to understand specifically why it's so important? If that's right, can you try to ask more specifically about your interest? Thanks. :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang thanks for the advice. Is it a more reasonable question now?

Comment: Yes, thank you, that clarifies your intent; I've retracted my close vote. I'm not sure, however, that there's a satisfying answer. Every open submanifold of a parallelizable manifold is parallelizable (so lots of examples exist). Conversely, a general homogeneous space is _not_ parallelizable (so Lie groups are atypical in some respect). I'd say the issue isn't an invariant metric, but the ability to fix a point $p_{0}$ and, for every point $p$, have a _distinguished diffeomorphism_ (smoothly varying with $p$) carrying $p_{0}$ to $p$. This viewpoint does little but restate the definition....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing is purely pedagogical: A parallelizable manifold is the one which has trivial tangent bundle. When one is first introduced to (locally trivial) fiber bundles, trivial bundles are easy comparing to the general bundles; computations are sometimes easier for trivial bundles. (Later on you just get used to the concept.)

Second, in the case of open manifolds $M$ (ones where each component is noncompact), there  is a beautiful theorem, due to Hirsch, which states that every open parallelizable $n$-dimensional manifold admits an local diffeomorphism $M\to R^n$.

See

Theorem 4.7 in

M. Hirsch, On imbedding differentiable manifolds in euclidean space. 
Ann. of Math. (2) 73 (1961) 566–571.

and, with more details:

Corollary 8.2 in

A. Phillips, Submersions of open manifolds. 
Topology 6 (1967) 171–206.

Thus, you can take any structure you have on $R^n$, e.g. complex structure, flat Riemannian metric, etc., and pull back it to $M$.

The most spectacular application of the Hirsch's immersion theorem is the "torus trick" of Kirby and Siebenmann.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This would be the exact answer I am looking for as it shows that parelellizable manifolds are in some sense simpler than others but after thinking a bit harder I'm not sure I quite under stand the second statement. I usually think of a manifold as inheriting a differentiable structure so I cannot think of a manifold locally homemorphic to $R^n$ which is not locally diffeormorphic to it (perhaps this is embarrassing for me). On the other hand I could see how maybe such a statement would be useful if it implied that on a parallellizable manifold exotic structures don't

Comment: exist, but this isn't true either as $R^4$ has exotic structures. Can you perhaps provide a source for the Hirsch theorem? Maybe looking at that could clear things up, thanks again

Comment: @RMary exotic $R^4$ admits an immersion in the standard $R^4$,  no contradiction here. I think you are confusing a local diffeomorphism with a diffeomorphism. I will look for a precise reference, the textbook reference is in the book by Eliashberg an Mishachev on h-principle.

Comment: @RMary actually, there are even "small" exotic $R^4$ we which embed smoothly in the standard $R^4$.

Comment: Dear studiosus, thank you very much I understand now and this is perfect

Answer (score 5):

A large class of structures on manifolds are defined using "reduction of the structure group" applied to the tangent bundle: these include, but are not limited to, orientations, spin structures, almost complex structures, almost symplectic structures, etc.

A parallelizable manifold admits all of these structures. Is that the sort of thing you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Parallelizable manifold is equivalent to the fact that the tangent bundle is trivial, so all the characteristic classes are zero, so is the euler number,... There is also a vector field which does not vanish at any point, a fact which is not true for every manifold.

The only parallelizable spheres are $S^1, S^3$ and $S^7$.

Comment: I was taking the tangent bundle being trivial (and the existence of nowhere vansihing linearly independent sections) as a definition of the manifold being parallellizable. I was wondering if it told us anything about the manifold outside the definition. Sorry, I'm aware that my question is vague. I will add this to the question

Comment: You just need the Euler characteristic to vanish for the existence of a nowhere vanishing vector field.